# How to set value for the property from a variable in the gitlab ci yml file

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

The below is a part of my gitlab yaml file

```
job1:
   stage : stage1
   script : echo "something" 
   when : on_success

job1:
   stage : stage1
   script : echo "something" 
   when : $VARIABLE
```

I want to set property "when" value to what i am referring in a variable. I have tried like this and it does not seem to be working. Is there anyway we could set this value dynamically using variables

Comment: I don't think so. What's the expected usage? How would the variable be set?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables directly in this key (see: [where variables can be used](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html)), but the proper way to set this value conditionally on a variable would probably be to use [`rules:when:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

```yaml
job1:
  script: "echo something"
  rules:
    # set when: to "always" when $VARIABLE == "value"
    - if: $VARIABLE == "value"
      when: always
    - when: on_success # the default when above rule(s) don't match
```